# Python Cryptography, Value Error: Could not deserialize key data, when using EC keys

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

The goal i am trying to achieve with this code is generating elliptic curve keys and storing them in a file to load at a later time.

I followed the instruction in the serialization and key loading section o the f elliptic curve section in the [documentation](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ec/#module-cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.ec). The only difference is the additional step of writing the bytes generated by the the    `private_bytes` function of the to a file and later loading the bytes again from the same file.
I even compared the bytes loaded from file to the initially created bytes and they are shown as being equal.

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding, ec
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization



if __name__ == '__main__':

    private_key = ec.generate_private_key(
        ec.SECP384R1(), default_backend()
    )
    private_key_pem = private_key.private_bytes(encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
                                            format=serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
                                            encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption()
                                            )

    print("Loading private key from bytes")
    private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(private_key_pem, password=None, backend=default_backend())
    print("Successfully loaded key from bytes")
    with open("ec_private_key", "wb") as sk:
        sk.write(private_key_pem)

    with open("ec_private_key", "rb") as sk:
        print(sk.read() == private_key_pem)
        private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(sk.read(), password=None, backend=default_backend())
```

This is the output I receive when running the above script:

```
Loading private key from bytes
Successfully loaded key from bytes
True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/michaelgraf/Desktop/train-user-client/backend/test.py", line 25, in <module>
    private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(sk.read(), password=None, backend=default_backend())
  File "/home/michaelgraf/Desktop/train-user-client/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/base.py", line 16, in load_pem_private_key
    return backend.load_pem_private_key(data, password)
  File "/home/michaelgraf/Desktop/train-user-client/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 1089, in load_pem_private_key
    password,
  File "/home/michaelgraf/Desktop/train-user-client/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 1315, in _load_key
    self._handle_key_loading_error()
  File "/home/michaelgraf/Desktop/train-user-client/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 1373, in _handle_key_loading_error
    raise ValueError("Could not deserialize key data.")
ValueError: Could not deserialize key data.
```

I am using python 3.7 and cryptography 2.8. Is there anything i could do differently when storing the keys in a file or generally? The keys need to be persisted to a file in some way to be stored for later use. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re calling `read` on the file twice. The first time works as intended, but when you call `read` for the second time in the next line, since you have reached the end of file, it returns an empty string. Obviously the empty string is not a valid key.

You need to ensure to only call `read` once. For example you could store the results in a variable and use that:

```
with open("ec_private_key", "rb") as sk:
    data = sk.read()
    print(data == private_key_pem)
    private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(data, password=None, backend=default_backend())
```